# DateTime value from Excel wrong for a milisecond

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datetime

So the following print screen should be quite self explanatory:

[image]

Three DateTimes, all should be the same, yet all are different. Looks like excel shows 11.04.2021 23.59.59.999 as 12.04.2021 already.

Now the issue is that I want to read the date from Cell A3. This should be 12.04.2021 00:00:00 but instead is read by C# as one millisecond less than that.

So my question is:

- Why?
- Is there a different way to fix this other than blindly adding a millisecond? Perhaps using the `DateTime.FromAODate(someDouble)'?

Comment: What you see is the result of `DateTime.FromOADate`. In the OADate format dates are stored as an integer offset from 1899-12-30 (no typo) and time as a fraction of 24 hours. Precision errors are unavoidable. Excel formats this double for display using the cell's style. When the style allows only seconds, the value is rounded up to the next second

Comment: You can check what the actual value of that field is by changing the cell's style to a number

Comment: Excel represents dates and times as a an offset in days from a specific date. This day offset is a floating point number. C# represents dates and times as an integral offset of 100 ns ticks from a specific date. I believe that C# will always truncate timestamps when required so `11.04.2021 23.59.59.9999` becomes `11.04.2021 23.59.59.999`. I don't know about Excel but it seems likely that it will round the floating point number so `11.04.2021 23.59.59.9999` becomes `12.04.2021 00.00.00`.

Comment: actually it is not 1 millisecond between [11.04.2021 00:00:00:000] y [12.04.2021 (...) ]. it is  1 day at least